# How to compute the homogeneity of a irreducible bundle with respect to the grading element of a parabolic subalgebra?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

This question pertains the BGG sequences discussed by Cap, Slovak, and Soucek in the paper found in the arXiv at https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0001164.pdf.

On the bottom of page 39 of this paper, there is a discussion about determining the order of differential operators between bundles in the BGG sequence by comparing the homogeneities (under the action of a grading element in $G_0$) of the bundles that the operator acts between. Namely, if one finds that the homogeneity under such a grading element of the domain of the operator is, say, $a$ and the homogeneity of the image is, say, $b$, then the order of the differential operator acting between them would be $b-a$.

According to a discussion I had with Michael Eastwood, one way that one could compute the homogeneity of a bundle in a BGG sequence labelled by a crossed Dynkin diagram and numbers over the nodes is by examining the column of the inverse Cartan matrix corresponding to the crossed nodes and computing the inner product of that column with the vector formed by the diagram labels.

Concretely, say we are examining
$$\mathfrak{so}(3) \hookrightarrow \mathfrak{so}(4,1)\,.$$
The corresponding Cartan matrix is
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 
        2 & -1 \\
        -2 & 2
       \end{pmatrix}\,,$$
so its inverse is
$$A^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix} 
        1 & \frac12 \\
        1 & 1
       \end{pmatrix}\,.$$

So, the recipe I was told by Michael would suggest that if I wanted to compute the the homogeneity of a Dynkin diagram labelled by $(a,b)$, then the action of the grading element on the highest weight would be given by $-(a+b)$, where we take the left-most column (the column "corresponding" to the crossed node) and apply a Euclidean dot-product to the values on the node.

I have several questions about this whole procedure, and any help for any of these questions would be great.

- Where did this recipe provided by Michael come from? How can I see that the action of the grading element on the root corresponding to the highest weight is given by this bizarre dot product involving a column from the inverse Cartan matrix? Can this be seen by some sort of matrix product of $w.A^{-1}$, where $w$ is the highest weight vector in the fundamental weight basis?
- When there is more than one node that is crossed, how does this procedure generalize? I have experimented some and seem to find that we just add the corresponding columns in the inverse Cartan matrix, but that seems ad hoc.
- How can I see that the order of a differential operator between two bundles corresponds to the difference in homogeneities of those two bundles?

As always, any help is appreciated. This material is hard for a physicist!

Comment: So some important context here is that the Cartan matrix represents a change in basis from the simple roots to the fundamental weights. Thus the columns (or rows depending on your precise def of the matrix some people transpose it) represent the simple roots written in the basis of the fundamental weights. Naturally the inverse Cartan has columns/rows given by the fundamental weights written in a basis of the simple roots

Comment: Yes - this is something I am aware of. This is in fact even more confusing, because it's the simple roots, not the weights, that are the natural basis for generators, which would lead me to think we should work in that basis when discussing the action of a grading element....

Comment: But for a general representation we have the action in terms of the fundamental weights. So in order to understand the action of the grading element (something we can define in terms of the simple roots) we have to convert that into the fundamental weight basis.

Comment: Explicitly, the grading element for a single crossed node is exactly the dual of the corresponding simple root (i.e. an element of the dual basis to the basis of simple roots) and the grading element for a series of crossed nodes is the sum of those for each crossed node. Then the action of a grading element $\xi = \sum_{\alpha_i \in S} \alpha_i^* \in \mathfrak{g}_0$ on a weight space $V_\omega$ is exactly $\omega(\xi) = \sum_{\alpha_i \in S} \omega(\alpha_i^*) $. Then $\omega(\alpha_i^*) $ can be found by the inner product specified.

Comment: This is remarkably helpful. While you were writing that comment, I was writing one up, as I believe I had come to the same conclusion you just mentioned. However, just so I can understand properly: is the reason the action of an element on a weight space is given by this inner product because one can write a vector in the weight space as a product of a bunch of ladder operators, that then can be commuted in the appropriate way with the grading element?

Comment: I would say it is more to do with the Riesz Representation Theorem: For an inner product space $V$ (in this case our CSA with the Killing form) and an element in the dual space $f \in V^*$ there is a unique $v\in V$ such that for all $w\in V$, $f(w) = (v,w)$.

Comment: I think I'm missing something here. On the one hand, we would expect that the dual of a simple root cannot be in the CSA. In fact, I think more fundamentally I don't understand your earlier comment: how can the grading element (an element of the CSA) be the dual of a simple root? Am I missing something obvious here? By the way - I wanted to thank you for all your help in the last few weeks. Much of this stuff isn't explained in great detail (but I'd love to see any references you might have!).

Comment: So the roots and weights live in the dual of the CSA: $\mathfrak{h}^*$ and thus their duals live in $(\mathfrak{h}^*)^* = \mathfrak{h}$. Then we can see that it is precisely the dual element by noticing $\alpha_j(\xi_{\alpha_i})$ is $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise. Always happy to answer questions. This area is adjacent to my own area and answering questions has forced me to actually learn some of the theory. As to references, have a look at Parabolic Geometries by Cap and Slovak if you haven't already.

Comment: Of course! I was confusing roots with the corresponding generators, which is my mistake. I suppose my last question is just how the difference in homogeneity degree of the bundles gets us the order of the differential operator. I have a notion that a derivative increases homogeneity degree, but I can't formalize why that should be true - I just see it from examples.

Comment: This is extending beyond my knowledge unfortunately although it makes sense to me in the following way. Let $s$ be a section of a $\mathfrak{g}$-rep $V$ over $M = G/P$. Then if $s$ is in a graded/filtered piece $V_i\leq V$, $ds \cong [\beta, s] \mod V_i$ where $\beta \in \Omega^1(\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p})$ is the solder form. Note that $\beta$ takes values exactly in the raising piece of $\mathfrak{g}$ (well, at least if we fix a complementary parabolic). I'm used to parabolics of height 1 where this can only raise the degree by 1 but I'm not sure if this holds for other cases

Comment: This was precisely my thinking. In trying to piece this all together, the only thing I am currently not understanding is a missing minus sign. If you do the computation as you have outlined, then in the diagram at the top of page 40 of the paper I referenced in the OP, the the top left map (labelled $a+1$) seems to map a higher homogeneity bundle to a lower one. And yet, that is supposed to be a differential operator of order $a+1$. I think this accounts for the minus sign noted by Michael in the OP, but I don't see why that's there. It might have something to do with the dualization?

Comment: It might simply be the convention. They (as do Baston/Eastwood) choose the ordering such that nilradical is on the positive side and so $\mathfrak{g}/\mathfrak{p}$ is then the negative side.